# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/Google/Android/gms/common/API/API$zzf;

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
```

I am getting above error at run time.

I set multiDexEnabled true, but I'm still getting the error.

I am not able to find reason behind it. There is no correct solution for this
question.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rewardchat.benefitomessenger-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rewardchat.benefitomessenger-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have also faced this issue while adding firebase auth in my project and issue was I have not added google auth as dependency in build.gradle. Adding below dependencies solved the problem

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

Comment: Solved it for me!

Comment: @RoadXY I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error due to dependency conflicts in Firebase. In particular, dependencies of the module Auth. In this case, updating the dependencies should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add like this in the project gradle file like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    //start here
    configurations.all {
 resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
   def requested = details.requested
       if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
          details.useVersion '12.0.1'
       }
       if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
          details.useVersion '12.0.1'
         }
       }
     }
    //end
     jcenter()
       maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to add the following to your gradle file dependencies:

```
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:5.8.4'
```

and sync gradle.

Comment: I can't see why a third party dependencies solves this.